# type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method in tensorflow model.predict

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])
])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
xs = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], dtype=float)
ys = np.array([.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5], dtype=float)
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1000)
return (model.predict(y_new))
```

this code giving error:

> type numpy.ndarray does not define **round** method in model.predict()

Comment: Please elaborate more. WHat is your `y_new` and its shape?

Comment: Also `dtype`.  I suspect object